# How can I set wide screen when using R markdown with html output?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to get a html output with R markdown but the output screen is very narrow. This causes a very limited dplyr outputs.

In ioslides there is an option like "widescreen : TRUE".

Is there some option like that when using plain html output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `CSS` to change the width of your output. Use

```
output: 
    html_document:
        css: styles.css
```

and put something like the following in `styeles.css`:

```
p {
  width: 200%;
}

pre {
  width: 200%;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Of course you may want to change the numbers to more suitable ones. The `p` block is your text, the `pre` your R codes and the `img` your images.